# Does a mass gain inertia against movement in all directions as it approaches the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, thought-experiment, warp-drives

If a mass moves along the x axis at near the speed of light, does it take as much energy to additionally accelerate the mass along the y axis as it does to accelerate it along the x axis by the same amount? (from a standing frame of reference)

I.e. does a mass spinning near the speed of light resist linear acceleration along its axis the same amount as it would resist acceleration to its rotation about the axis?

If you have two objects with equal resting mass with parallel spin axes, and one is spinning close to the speed of light while the other is barely spinning, do they require different amounts of outside force to accelerate the along their spin axes?

Answer (score 1):

I was originally going to go on a long rant about 4-forces, but it then occurred to me that this question can easily be reformulated, and addressing it that way will be much quicker and easier to follow.

Let's rephrase the question as: "Are the individual components of proper acceleration Lorentz invariant?"

Well, to start with: the magnitude of the proper acceleration is definitely Lorentz invariant.

Unfortunately, that's where the easy part ends. While everyone will agree on the magnitude of the proper acceleration, we can't all agree on the values of each individual component. This is because observers in different reference frames have different coordinate systems. While our coordinate systems can be converted into one another using Lorentz transforms, we're left with the fact that what you see as an acceleration purely along one axis won't be the same for me being in a different reference frame.

That is, the individual components of proper acceleration are **not** Lorentz invariant. So, whether a mass is moving along the x-axis **does** influence how much energy it takes to accelerate it by some amount along any choice of axis. In some reference frames, all of that energy will go towards accelerating it along the chosen axis, while in others only some will.

Comment: Forgive my naive comment: Isn't this true for all proper four vectors? Or is there a (non-trivial) four vector that consists of four Lorentz scalars? Can there be such a thing? Can we, by induction, extend this to all objects that transform under Lorentz transformation? And isn't this already true for vectors under rotations? Maybe there is even a general (if slightly more complicated) statement for Lie-groups here? (I know a tiny bit about invariants, but they generally don't form vectors, as far as I know.). Am I getting this totally wrong?

Comment: @FlatterMann I don't believe such a thing is possible.

Comment: You mean a vector with components that are all invariant or a general statement that it can't exist?

Comment: @FlatterMann A non-trivial 4-vector wherein all components are Lorentz scalars.